# Convert Images into WebP

Tags: wordpress

I am using a WordPress website. I want to convert my images into WebP format. Could anyone expert help me how I can do it for myself. I am not an expert but can do a few bit modifications. If you can provide an address like go to this file then find this etc.

Thank You.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-converter-for-media/ this can work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67183333/wordpress-convert-image-to-webp-format-programmatically-with-gd-image-engine

Answer (score 0):

To convert the images in WebP, the simplest way is to use an online converter.

Online Converter for converting Images to WebP : https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-webp

And, if you want a WordPress plugin go with this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-converter-for-media/

But I recommend the 1st option.

Comment: But i need an code that add into my file and simple convert it. I don't want to use any plugin.